# Is there a generic way to add disguise as a class skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, pathfinder-society, disguise

Is there some generic way to add disguise as a class skill to any class that doesn't have it?  For example, many traits add other skills, but I haven't been able to find one for disguise.  I'm looking for a PFS-legal method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The feat [Cosmopolitan](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/advancedFeats.html#cosmopolitan) gives you access to two INT, WIS, or Charisma based skills as class skill, and the [Keeper of the Veil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/keeper-of-the-veil-regional-qadira) regional trait gives you access to Bluff or Disguise as a class skill and also grants a +1 bonus to both of those skills.

Comment: How complete do you want to be? (*Note:* Already upvoted.) An oread or a goblin can take the trait [Statuesque](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/statuesque-oread) or [Ugly Swine](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/ugly-swine), respectively, to gain Disguise as a class skill. (Seriously, who knew this was so difficult? I mean besides the querent, obviously.)

Comment: There's also the Almost Human trait which requires being a Half-orc (or also taking Adopted).  I suggest going here http://pfsdb.com/traits whenever you have a question about traits that can be easily grepped.

Comment: While these other suggestions are good, the question is for a generic method to add the skill to any class.